# Safari number input stepUp/stepDown not functioning with empty value

Tags: javascript, macos, safari

I'm running into a strange issue on Safari while creating a custom React number input component. We have two buttons that, on click, call stepUp and stepDown on an input element. Here is an example:

```
<button onclick="document.getElementById('myInputId').stepDown()">-</button>
<input id="myInputId" type="number" />
<button onclick="document.getElementById('myInputId').stepUp()">+</button>
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/great-mccarthy-s2ybz

Using macOS Safari, when the input box is empty and stepUp/stepDown is called, I get the error

```
InvalidStateError: The object is in an invalid state.
```

This issue seems to affect (at least) Safari 14.0.1 to latest.

I am able to work around this by, on click, setting the value of the element to 0 if empty and then calling stepDown/stepUp, but I am wondering if there is something I am doing wrong here that might save me from having to implement this extra step.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why not declare 0 through the HTML? `<input id="myInputId" type="number" value="0" />`

Answer (score 0):

the best solution for handling this is exactly what you mentioned. Setting the value of the input to 0.

From [Apple's document archive](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariHTMLRef/Articles/InputTypes.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008055-SW1), the number input is expecting a match of `\d* or [0-9]*`. This was the latest documentation I could find, I hope this helps!

```
<button onclick="document.getElementById('myInputId').stepDown()">-</button>
<input id="myInputId" type="number" value="0" />
<button onclick="document.getElementById('myInputId').stepUp()">+</button>
```